# How can I run a dedicated server without Steam?

Tags: steam, source-engine

Steam won't let me have two instances running with the same user logged in.

Does that mean I cannot run a dedicated server on a PC (for example, for Left 4 Dead 2) *and* play from another machine?

Is there a way to run the dedicated server without running Steam? Is there a configuration option I'm missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to have Steam running, just get the actual dedicated server (srcds).

This is a great site to get you started: [Install SRCDS on Windows](http://www.srcds.com/db/engine.php?subaction=showfull&id=1097362093).

Comment: yea usually the server software is separate from the game itself if you are running a dedicated. downloading the software and running it will allow steam users to connect to it. However you have to make sure you have it all set up right and what not to allow outside connections.