# Steam slow large inventory: Can it be split easily on 2+ accounts?

Tags: steam

As the title says: is there any easy way to split the inventory between accounts EASILY ? like using the same mobile for all when transfering...

Thanks :-)

Comment: I think the answer is no, sorry

Answer (score 1):

The only way to transfer items between accounts is via the trading system. Trading between two accounts you own has the same limitations as trading with friends or strangers and is somewhat cumbersome when trading a lot of items.

[You can use the same mobile phone number for multiple accounts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/258976/68284), and you are allowed to have multiple accounts, so there is no problem there.