# Can two people play the same game on the same account?

Tags: steam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to play two different Steam games on the same account at the same time?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3040/is-it-possible-to-play-two-different-steam-games-on-the-same-account-at-the-same)

I bought the Call of Duty game, but I was wondering if someone else could log into my Steam account at the same time, so that we can play multiplayer. Is that possible? Or do they need another account and therefore another game CD?

Comment: As far as I know Steam log you out as soon as a other computer log on the same account

Comment: idk about COD but i could do that with Terraria.

Answer (score 2):

Steam will kick one of you off. Steam will see that two people are using the same account and will kick one of the two of you off. He needs to buy a separate COD account.