# Could a member of my family and I play a game in Steam at the same time?

Tags: steam

I have bought a game, but a member of my family couldn't because of $$ and I was thinking if I can do this:

- 1. Add his/her computer to the list of family share of steam to let him/her see and play my games (I already have done that).
- 2. Block steam (and possibly the game too) in my computer with the firewall to go offline.
- 3. Disconnect internet (if 2 doesn't work).
- 4. Start the game in both computers (one online and one offline (the offline will be me)).

Before this, I could actually let him/her play my games when I don't play them, and going offline apparently don't block my games.

If I do this, do he/she could play it? (**I don't care to go offline or lose achievements, but I care if I could get banned if I do this**).

Also, he/she'll buy it, but meanwhile I was thinking if I can do this.

I have read [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/3042/134955) and apparently it can be done, but I want to know if this is risky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### No.

The [Steam family sharing FAQ](http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing) explicitly says this is not allowed.

> ***Can two users share a library and both play at the same time?***
>
> No, a shared library may only be accessed by one user at a time.

If you try to get creative to work around the technical limitations of the steam family sharing, you are risking Valve's wrath, including VAC-bans. From the same [Steam family sharing FAQ](http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing):

> ***Will I be punished for any cheating or fraud conducted by other users while playing my games?***
>
> Your Family Library Sharing privileges may be revoked and your account may also be VAC banned if your library is used by others to conduct cheating or fraud. Additionally, VAC-banned games cannot be shared. We recommend you only authorize familiar computers you know to be secure. And as always, never give your password to anyone.

It's unclear if Valve will actually detect and hand out bans for this sort of thing, but the safer way is to not risk it.

Comment: This is very informative. We will then wait to get more cash. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or, alternatively, you could use steam family sharing: http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing

It's official and everything :)

Edit: I stand corrected.  Looks like the terms do ban it.  Ignore this answer.  Although... looks like it's not an instaban process, because I *know* that both I and a family member have played the same thing, at the same time, from my library.

Comment: I'm already in family sharing, but we can't play the same game at the same time.

Comment: That's interesting - both I and the brother in law ended up playing kerbal at the same time, from my library.  Situational perhaps?