# Two persons play at same time on Steam?

Tags: steam, euro-truck-simulator-2, mirrors-edge

Today I played an offline game (like Euro Truck Simulator 2) on my personal steam account on my laptop. My daughter wanted to play Mirror's Edge on the desktop computer on the SAME!!!!!! account.

Steam kicked me from my account because she run that game, closing my game. I am not using Family Share, so I don't understand why this happened. How can I prevent this in the future?

Comment: I have proposed an edit that removes the (mini-)rant about Steam and instead makes the question focus on the facts. If I misunderstood details of your question, please edit the question to correct that.

Comment: @Sumurai8 While that section is a bit ranty, it also includes a lot of _spesific_ details on the situation and what the asker is aiming for. I see no reason to truncate this. Also, the tag `steam` shouldn't be removed, singe the question isn't soly about `steam-family-sharing`. I'd see only the game tags as superfulous to the question.

Comment: @DJ What are you talking about? The steam tag is still there. The rant contains the following facts: there are 2 accounts (and OP both owns them), OP says that he would not have that problem without steam (but I doubt they bought a spare copy of the game to test that theory), they both want to play at the same time (which should be obvious in the edited version) and OP says they don't use family share (which is stated explicitly in the edited version). What important information is in the original question that is missing in the edited version?

Comment: @Sumurai8 Huh. Don't know why, but I tought the removed tag was the 'steam' one. I was wrong about that. But I do still think that the original post decribed the situation more accurately. For example, you seem to assume that the desktop is "on a different account". The original never states this explicitly and knowing steam, unless Family Sharin is being used, Steam shouldn't behave like it does.

Comment: why edited my ask and you change it to wrong question? -_-

Comment: Alright I got answer in this question:
http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3040/is-it-possible-to-play-two-different-steam-games-on-the-same-account-at-the-same?rq=1

Comment: Glad you found the answer. I marked this question to be voted as duplicate. Sorry for the edit-hassle. Arqade allows users to suggest edits and even pretty low level users can vote on those suggestions. Unfortunately this suggestion got through even with the inaccuracies. But, to be fair, it would have been logical to assuem you'd try this with different accounts, seeing that Steam is _actively designed_ to _prevent_ what you were trying. Honestly, you might want to seek out DRM-free options next time you buy games.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you using 2 total different accounts or there might be something wrong with your lan network.

Steam wouldnt kick you for 2 seperate accounts both logged in.
It will only kick you if you use the same account because of obvious reason.

The reason why the game itself closed is most likely because your steam account was logged off making steam close every app that was opened with steam.

My advice would be to check the accounts that log in on the desktop and laptop and compare them.

Another thing that could be it is a complete different thing but thats that both laptop and desktop used the same ip adress from your local network, kicking you off from your connection and gave the internet to the desktop.

Would say check your network configuration if you both use the same ip adress by accident.

If this doesnt solve the issue i dont know but its what i would do first.

Ps. When this happens do you get any pop ups with errors or does it display anything at all? This way we can get a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: It same account! That moderator change my question. Is SAME account and Steam log me off. And this is NOT family share. I am just loged in on two computers which are my.

Comment: And no, I have set up IP address for laptop and for computer (static IP from router).

Comment: And yes I got message in my native language. If I remember correctly it was something like that: "Your steam account is needed somewhere else so you will be logged off." what is stupid because before run game I can be logged in on laptop and PC.

Comment: @IdolwSzutrab okay you answered the question. You cant login twice on the same account. Thats just how steam works. Reason is the disconnect and thats why your game closed

Comment: Well nothing we can do to help you with that except say avoid steam. Only thing you can do is go to the steam forums and suggest it and hope they will implent it if you can get enough support for it